# Относительный импорт в Python

Tags: python

С некоторых пор (как отменили относительный импорт) не могу нормально решить такой вопрос:

Предположим, структура программы

```
app/
    __init__.py
    foo/
        __init__.py
        handler.py
```

Как из модуля *handler.py* загрузить что-либо из пакета *foo*?

Всё дело в том, что изначально имя пакета *foo* неизвестно, загружаю я его с помощью *importlib*.

Пока я нашёл такой костыль:
обрезаю переменную **__name__**, которая в *handler.py* равна **'foo.handler'**, т.е. так

```
foo_name = __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
```

а потом загружаю необходимый мне модуль

```
needle_module = importlib.import_module('.' + <имя модуля>, foo_name)
```

но, как-то, не кошерно это...

Answer (score 2):

Я вот смотрю на вашу схему и вижу в ней что и сам хендлер ваш в этом же пакете, так спрашивается зачем мучатся когда достаточно имя файла написать??

собственно видел такое

```
mod=__import__("attr")
```

где attr имя файла attr.py

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но так не получится ))
attr.py будет искаться в директории app.

Answer (score 1):

Может добавить путь в sys.path?

Comment: А вообще у меня такое ощущение, что архитектура проекта неправильно спроектирована.

Comment: Не люблю этот sys.path, честно говоря, от него немало сюрпризов может всплыть...
Нет, дело не в архитектуре. Есть скрипт, сканирующий файлы и передающий их на обработку. Так вот обработчик прописан в конфигурации и загружается динамически.

Comment: Я, наверное, сложно объяснил свою ситуацию ))
просто требуется записать такую операцию

    from . import <имя модуля>

чтобы можно было использовать переменную

Comment: Мне кажется, что тогда тут вариант только с *importlib*.
На мой взгляд, ваш код(приложенный к топику) должен работать не намного медленнее, чем *from . import module*.

Правда я не до конца понимаю какова цель данной программы.
Если нужна система подгружающая модули из заранее неизвестного пакета, то может лучше воспользоваться готовыми наработками типа [Yapsy][1].


  [1]: http://yapsy.sourceforge.net/#

Comment: Спасибо за линк, посмотрю, что за пакет ))
Давно ищу стоящую систему загрузки модулей, но как-то не получается...

Comment: @Stan Есть еще неплохой ман по созданию системы управления плагинами http://habrahabr.ru/post/79513/

Answer (score 0):

In handler.py:

```
from ..module import function
```